# Multiprocessing vs Using a worker dyno

Tags: python, flask, heroku, multiprocessing

I am still new to using heroku and in my application there is a heavy image rendering process that can take upwards of 30 minutes. It creates frames of a video by moving the pixels of an original picture, then getting a frame, then moving the pixels some more, then grabbing another frame, like that until the specified amount of frames is made.

I was thinking of using multiprocessing so that I could output a progress bar to the web front end while the python backend does this heavy lifting. Until I came across dynos and specifically worker dynos.

I was wondering if I should use multiprocessing or worker dynos for a use case like this?